# python.pil: command not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I am trying to follow [these](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-seafile-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10-with-apache2-and-mariadb-support/) instructions for setting up Seafile on ubunutu linux. When I get to step 3, Install Seafile Dependencies, I get an error saying `bash: python-pil: command not found`. I managed to run the first line without issues, does anyone know how to get past this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have put a newline in there before the `python-pil`; that's not a command, it's just one of the arguments. The entire command starting with the `sudo apt` should all be one line; don't hit return or enter until the very end. Like this:

```
sudo apt install python2.7 libpython2.7 python-setuptools python-pil python-ldap python-urllib3 ffmpeg python-pip python-mysqldb python-memcache python-requests
```